# I want to show first 10 rows from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

this is my code for this purpose

`$sql_s="SELECT column FROM products LIMIT 10 WHERE id_product={$id}";`

Comment: `LIMIT` goes after the `WHERE` clause. error checking would have signaled that syntax error. RTFM https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the time to **read**: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: To get the FIRST 10 You should use an ORDER BY but without any knowledge of what you called the auto increment column or even if you have one it is rather difficult to be more specific about the sort you would need to do

Answer (score 4):

`LIMIT 10` should be after the `WHERE` clause.

```
$sql_s = "SELECT column FROM products WHERE id_product={$id} LIMIT 0, 10";
```

**Edit 1**

This link helps with debugging `MySQLi` (assuming your are using that).

http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/

Comment: That does not necessarily return the first 10 records. It returns 10 records in unpredictable order

Comment: PHP's error reporting does not signal MySQL syntax errors. Unknownst to us as to which MySQL API they are using to connect with.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Shouldn't this comment be on the question?

Comment: @JonStirling Yes it should. Was only trying to catch the OP's eye so maybe having used this answer he might realise with a bit of effort on his behalf he could get 'Script47' to do all his work for him.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm getting a negative vibe, maybe it's just me (if it is then ignore this) but is something wrong?

Comment: No far from it. I saw your answer was just about what I was going to post, so I did not bother. But I rememebered OP asked for FIRST 10. Thought I might prompt the OP=Questioner to add a bit more detail so you could make your answer absolutely complete, rather than just the best you could manage with the little data provided to us

Comment: @RiggsFolly ah my bad, I thought you were having a go at me for spoon feeding him/her.

Comment: God if I did that all the time, we might only answer 1 question a day. Most OP would not recognise a spoon if it was waved past their mouths

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.;

Comment: @RiggsFolly no need to apologize, I made the mistake.